# Android Studio - Can't move or drag buttons freely

Tags: android-layout, android-studio, android-button

I'm new to Android Studio (working on Windows) and I am now using Buttons for the first time. I'm using them inside a TabHost. It seems that I can't move/drag the buttons to anywhere I want in the design, they just stay at the top of the design. I've searched this on Google and someone suggested a RelativeLayout instead of a LinearLayout. I've switched layouts already and I still can't move the Buttons as I want.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance